# I can't find the exact ZIP program that bypass the "file name encryption" when viewing an encrypted file

Tags: encryption

I encrypted a file with "Encrypt file names" enabled ([using Winrar Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBiW0.jpg)) so that someone won't see what's inside unless it was successfully unpacked with its password.

But I look to [this](https://www.peazip.org/encrypt-filenames.html) site and it says:
 "ZIP format lacks this feature, meaning this option will have no effect and archive TOC will always be readable before providing the correct password even if the data is encrypted"

What ZIP program exactly is the site referring? Tried googling "zip archiver windows" but top result is 7zip.

I can't seem to find the "ZIP" program that the site is talking about.

I would like to install it so I can try if the "file name encryption" really will have no effect with that specific ZIP applicaton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What ZIP program exactly is the site referring?

They are talking about any program that can create a `.ZIP` archive.  This would include 8zip and WinRAR.

> I would like to install it so I can try if the "filename encryption" really will have no effect with that specific ZIP application.

This means if you use WinRAR or any program that supports the `.ZIP` file format, then the TOC of any `.ZIP` file will not actually be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Simple work-around:

- Put all files in `folder A` and Zip without encryption.
- Now Zip the file created above, `folder A.zip`, to `OtherName.zip`, encrypting it that new Zip archive.

On trying to open `OtherName.zip`, the user *can* see `folder A.zip`, but *cannot* see the file structure inside without the password.

Comment: "Of course, that means entering the password twice" -- Or just don't encrypt the inner archive? It's already encrypted in the outer archive.

Comment: @duskwuff, Thanks! The answer will be modified to reflect that.